# How to add a DataTrigger programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, datatrigger

I need to add a DataTrigger dynamically based on user interaction with a search function, so it cannot be done in XAML. However, the basic aim of what I am trying to do can be seen from the XAML code below. It needs to change the visibility of a button based on a ToggleButton's IsChecked state.

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Name="myToggleButton" />

<Button Name="myButton">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button>
```

This is what I have in C# to try to produce the same functionality of the above XAML.

C#:

```
ToggleButton myToggleButton = new ToggleButton();
Button myButton = new Button();
Style style = new Style( typeof( Button ) );
DataTrigger tbChecked = new DataTrigger() 
{ 
    Binding = new Binding( "IsChecked" ) { Source = myToggleButton },
    Value = true
},
            tbNotChecked = new DataTrigger() 
{ 
    Binding = new Binding( "IsChecked" ) { Source = myToggleButton },
    Value = false
};
tbChecked.Setters.Add( new Setter( Button.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible ) );
tbNotChecked .Setters.Add( new Setter( Button.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed ) );
style.Triggers.Add( tbChecked );
style.Triggers.Add( tbNotChecked );
myButton.Style = style;
```

For the life of me, I have not been able to figure out why it won't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of user interaction is needed to activate the trigger? I can't really think of a case where you couldn't use XAML for the DataTrigger..

Comment: Also can you clarify what you mean by "won't work"? Does the visibility not toggle? I'm also not clear about where `myToggleButton` and `myButton is in your code, do you manually add it to the Visual Tree? And is this your complete code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rachel. The reason I can't use XAML, and perhaps I just don't know something that makes this available, is that there are an unknown number of "parent" togglebuttons every time a search is performed. Also, there is always an unknown number of "child" buttons attached to those togglebuttons for each of the searches. Unless there's a way to dynamically populate my grid with the search results using those controls, I cannot use XAML to do the triggering. Although, I'll admit that I may be missing something there, too. I'm still relatively new to wpf.

Comment: As for "won't work," yes, the visibility toggle does not happen. This is not my complete code, but I figured it was concise enough to completely cover the functionality I was looking for. I do add the buttons and togglebuttons to a grid, but where I put them doesn't matter to this particular functionality. Does that clear everything up for you?

Comment: @Lazovis your code works 100% correctly for me just copy + pasting and adding each button to a stackpanel. Perhaps there's something else going on with the positioning of your button.

Comment: _"This is not my complete code, but I figured it was concise enough to completely cover the functionality I was looking for"_ -- that appears to not be the case. As so often happens when questioners fail to provide a _complete_ code example. Note that that doesn't mean you should post your _complete code_; you need to compose a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you have a dynamic # of something, the common solution is to draw them using an `ItemsControl`. You can set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to anything you want, which could include a toggle button with this data trigger. If you do want to use this method though, do you set the `Visibility` property directly on the button at all? Properties set on the object take precedence over any triggered properties, so that would cause the behavior you are describing. See MSDN's [Dependency Property Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing) for more information

Comment: Take note that you are *not* toggling the visibility. You set the value to `Collapsed` when `IsChecked` it is either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe, you can try this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox x:Name="switchCheckBox" Content="Show/Hide" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
    <Button Content="Test Button" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=switchCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" Padding="25,5"/>

</StackPanel>
```